# How to integrate Google Map in Objective c?

Tags: ios, dictionary, sdk

I am new to iOS and have to show Google Map having two restaurant  locations with different lat and long in Los Angeles area. I need to make sure if user clicks on map it will allow user to get directions to that specific restaurant. So if all locations are on one map, user would need to click on desired restaurant/pin on map and get directions - correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this I found it before

```
    In -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker// This method will get call after taping marker pin(GMSMapView map view delegate method).
{ get the latitude and longitude of that marker.

}

Take the latitude and longitude of current location

Now Draw route between two location
//Download LRouteController from this link  https://github.com/lukagabric/LRouteController

//This will draw link between two co-ordinate
//In .h File declare LRouteController *_routeController;
 if ([_coordinates count] > 1)
    {
        //Draw line between two co-ordinate
        [_routeController getPolylineWithLocations:_coordinates travelMode:TravelModeDriving andCompletitionBlock:^(GMSPolyline *polyline, NSError *error) {
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
            else if (!polyline)
            {
                NSLog(@"No route");
                [_coordinates removeAllObjects];
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No route" message:@"No route available for this route." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            else
            {
                //Drow route
                _markerStart.position = [[_coordinates objectAtIndex:0] coordinate];
                _markerStart.map = googleMapview;

                _markerFinish.position = [[_coordinates lastObject] coordinate];
                _markerFinish.map = googleMapview;

                _polyline = polyline;
                _polyline.strokeWidth = 3;
                _polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                _polyline.map = googleMapview;
            }
        }];
    }


//If you are unable to get taped pin latitude and longitude the you can use custom GMSMarker
Ex: @interface MapMarker : GMSMarker //Create new file of GMSMarker
@property (nonatomic, strong) coOrdinateData *data;(CoOrdinateData is NSObject class declare lat and long value)
@end

While adding marker on map use 
 MapMarker *marker= [[MapMarker alloc]init];

            [marker setPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LocationAtual.coordinate.latitude,LocationAtual.coordinate.longitude)];
  marker.data=data;//Take lat and long value in object class and pass object class in marker object
After typing on map marker you can get value like
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
NSString *strLat = ((MapMarker *)marker).data.lat ;
NSString *strLong = ((MapMarker *)marker).data.long ;
//Add both the current location and marker  latitude and longitude in _coordinates and draw route.
}
```

Comment: if you want the steps to add google map just see this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/?hl=en

Comment: i would like to thank you first.I have to show to locations only 1.Los Angeles,CA 900362          2.Sherman Okas,CA 91403

Comment: GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:34.08   longitude:-118.336545 zoom:6];
    _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_mapView.frame camera:camera];
    _mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = _mapView;
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.083811, -118.336545);
    marker.title = @"";
    marker.snippet = @" ";
    marker.map = _mapView;
    
    ;

Comment: @RakeshBiswal: please edit that code into your question - it is barely readable in comments.